# compile android-support:support-annotations in java module. is it possible?

Tags: android, robolectric

Im trying to run my Robolectric tests on a Java module separate from my Android application. The problema is that one of my testing dependencies (com.squareup.assertj:assertj-android:1.0.0) requires 'android-support:support-annotations:20.0.0'. Can I compile this last dependency although being only present inside the android-sdk?

Thank you

Comment: You don't need Robolectric for code that doesn't touch Android API. For assertions just use core assertj

Comment: Hi! But I wanted to use asserts-android since I need robolectric for code that touches the AndroidAPI! It makes the code more readable. But I wanted the code in other module to separate robolectric tests from instrumentation testing. @EugenMartynov

Comment: Remove `@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)` for tests that are not touching any android API. Use `import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat;` instead of `import static org.assertj.android.api.Assertions.assertThat;`. You will also get huge speed in run tests

Comment: @EugenMartynov good point! thank you